# kubernetes drain master node before a reboot

Tags: kubernetes

If I were to do a sudo reboot on a Kubernetes master node, would Kubernetes be smart enough to drain itself from the cluster?

Say I have a web service running one pod that happened to land on the master node. If I were to "sudo reboot" the master node, would he tell another node to spin up a  copy before he died?

Answer (score 1):

This is not expected behavior for Kubernetes. Actually, K8s represent master node as the [Control plane](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/#kubernetes-control-plane) for the all cluster managed operations. The main contributors on each Node are: [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kubelet), [kube-proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-proxy), and Container run-time software (Docker, cri-o, etc.).

Whenever you wish to reboot OS on the particular Node(Master, worker), K8s cluster engine does not aware for that action and it keeps all the cluster related events in [ETCD](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#etcd) key value storage, backing up the most recent data. As soon as you wish carefully prepare cluster Node reboot, you might have to adjust [Maintenance](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cluster-management/#maintenance-on-a-node) job on this Node in order to drain it from scheduling and gracefully terminate all the existing Pods.

If you compose any relevant K8s resource within defined set of [replicas](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/), then [ReplicationController](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/) guarantees that a specified number of pod replicas are running at any one time through each available Node. It simply re-spawns Pods if they failed health check, deleted or terminated, matching desired replicas.